# Is there any good, theory-neutral definition of long-distance reflexives in the literature?

Tags: syntax, terminology, anaphora, binding-theory, reflexive

Long distance reflexives/anaphora/binding are much discussed in the literature, particularly among generativists, but while there seems to be rough agreement on what constitutes a long-distance reflexive, I can't find a good, theory-neutral definition of it.

The general usage seems to be 'a reflexive whose anaphoric distance is longer than what English allows', reflecting the field's traditional anglocentricity, but even that is vague and imprecise. For example, (1) is not acceptable in English:

> (1) *The father of John(i) is looking at himself(i) in the mirror

But it's not clear that the distance between 'John' and 'himself' is longer than in (2), which is acceptable in English:

> (2) John(i) is looking at himself(i) in the mirror

So I'm looking for a good, citable definition, not laden in theoretical terminology, under which it is clear whether (1) is a type of long-distance reflexive. Thanks!

Comment: (I realise this isn't a very intellectually meaningful question, but I asked in the 'small questions' post on Reddit and have no replies so far. Sorry if you find this silly!)

Comment: There really isn't a single theory-independent answer because "distance" is a metric that is defined in terms of some concept of "structure"; it's not linear, and theory-related terms like "command" and "subordinate" are going to have to be used for the non-temporal dimensions. Like the famous constraint on English anaphors, which may not both precede and command their antecedent. Linguists are agreed on the metaphor of "distance"; but they each define their own metric over their own vector space.

Comment: @jlawler I realise there isn't a single definition, but this is more of a practical question than a conceptual one. I'd like a good definition that I can cite and stick to...

Comment: Simplest thing to do is list all the cases where it fails and describe them each as being conditioned by some variant of C-command customized to your practical needs. That's what grammarians do when they can't find a connecting thread.

Comment: @jlawler Thanks, but I guess I was unclear in stating my intentions... I'm writing about the phenomenon of long-distance binding in general, rather than doing actual syntactc analysis, and that's why I need a nice, precise definition to define the scope of the essay! ><

Comment: The definition comes after the data; you can't say anything theoretical until you have some evidence it occurs.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not trying to do anything theoretical really... I just want a definition I can use to define the scope of my essay (it's not a term paper or anything; I don't get to choose the topic, because if I did, I'd choose something more concrete, like logophoric reflexives). So basically, I'd like a definition that Haspelmath would have used if he were to write about the long-distance reflexives...

Comment: Ask your teacher, eh? Whoever assigned the topic must have some idea what it means, at least if they're going to grade it. If you don't want to do the basic research, you'd have to find the sources that have done it already. What have you read already?

Comment: @jlawler I took a look at the Marathi and Norwegian data in Dalrymple (1993), and also looked at some other Nordic data in a pdf I found earlier. I've flipped through Yan Huang's book and he has a plenty of examples I'm planning to use - his discussion, classification etc is great, but in the definition he just used the term 'local domain', which was a bit vague. I've located Sells' paper but haven't read it yet. I saw some Chomskyan work but they usually contained too much theory-internal stuff so I mostly didn't read them haha...